# How to get the UID from Agora.io

Tags: agora.io

How to get the UID from Agora.io

When customers join the video call that is made by Agora.io, Agora assign the UID to each customers.
So,Please let me know how can I get the UID from Agora.

I have already tried with this URL:
https://docs.agora.io/en/help/integration-issues/string

Thank you.